# How does Rails know what the content type of an uploaded file is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, content-type, rack

When a file is uploaded through the form in a Rails application, then in the controller I get an instance of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, which has `#content_type` already magically set. How does it do that, how does Rails know what the content type of the uploaded file is?

I noticed that when testing file upload, you have to pass the content type manually to `#fixture_file_upload`. But why? Can't the content type be determined in the same way?

Comment: AFAIK that comes from Rack which just uses whatever the browser says it is.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I see now in Rack that it takes the content type from headers.